# Compute $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(f(k/n) - f((k-1)/n))\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}f(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> Let $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and let $(a_n)_{n>0}$ and $(b_n)_{n>0}$ be two sequences such that $$\displaystyle{ a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n{f \left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right) \cdot \int_\frac{k-1}{n}^\frac{k}{n}}{f(t)dt}},$$
>
> $$\displaystyle  b_n = \sum_{k=1}^n{f \left(\frac{k}{n}\right) \cdot \int_\frac{k-1}{n}^\frac{k}{n}}{f(t)dt}, $$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*$.
>
> a) Prove that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{(b_n - a_n)} = 0}$.
>
> b) Compute $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{n(b_n - a_n)}}$.

I have managed to solve a).

**Proof for a) :**

From the mean value theorem, we know that $\displaystyle{\exists c_k \in \left(\frac{k-1}{n}, \frac{k}{n}\right)}$ such that $\displaystyle{\int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}}{f(t)dt} = \frac{1}{n}f(c_k)}$

So, $b_n = \displaystyle{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n {f(c_k) \cdot f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n{\left(\frac{f(c_k) + f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)}{2}\right)^2 \cdot 4 - (f(c_k))^2 - \left(f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)^2}}$.

Since $f$ has the intermediate value property, then $\exists x_k \in \displaystyle{\left(c_k, \frac{k}{n}\right) \subset \left(\frac{k-1}{n}, \frac{k}{n} \right)}$ such that $\displaystyle{\frac{f(c_k) + f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)}{2} = f(x_k)}$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n = \int_0^1{(f(t))^2dt}}$.

Using the same method, $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = \int_0^1{(f(t))^2dt}}$, so $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}{(b_n - a_n)} = 0}$.

I have trouble solving b). I tried using the same method but it doesn't work, not unless $f$ is differentiable (so I can use Lagrange's theorem).

$\displaystyle{n(b_n - a_n) = \sum_{k=1}^n{f(c_k) \left( f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) - f\left(\frac{k-1}{n} \right) \right)}}$ and if $f$ is differentiable, then $\displaystyle{f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) - f\left(\frac{k-1}{n} \right) = \frac{1}{n}f'(c_k)}$.

Comment: Riemann sum plus mean value theorem do the job here

Comment: If you can solve this for differentiable functions, you can do it for every continuous function, by density. Thus... please explain what you do to solve this for differentiable functions.

Comment: Try setting $g(x)=f(x)^2/2$ and compare the terms to changes in the value of $g$.

Comment: Sorry..... my bad!

Comment: This seems to be harder than one might think. Can you tell where the problem comes from?

Comment: @MartinR It's from a Romanian mathematics magazine called "Gazeta Matematica". Every month there are 13 new problems for each grade of eduation (I'm in the 12th and last grade), some of them are easy, but others may be difficult. This very problem is from the December/2017 number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here we construct a continuous function $f : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ such that the associated sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ satisfy

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} 3^n(b_{3^n} - a_{3^n}) = \infty \tag{*}$$

### 1. Construction

Pick $0 < y_2 < y_1 < 1$ and define $\psi : \mathbb{R} \to [0, 1]$ by

$$ \forall x \in [0, 3) \ : \quad  \psi(x) = \begin{cases}
3y_1, & x \in [0, 1) \\
3(y_2 - y_1), & x \in [1, 2) \\
3(1 - y_2), & x \in [2, 3)
\end{cases} $$

and extend by $3$-periodicity, i.e. $\psi(x) = \psi(x \text{ mod } 3)$. Then define $f_n : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$ f_n(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \psi(3^i t) \, dt. $$

We will prove the following claim.

> **Theorem.** $f_n$ converges uniformly to a continuous function $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$. Moreover, for all $n \geq 1$ and $k \in \{1,\cdots,3^n\}$, we have $f(\frac{k}{3^n}) = f_n(\frac{k}{3^n})$ and
>
> $$ \int_{\frac{k-1}{3^n}}^{\frac{k}{3^n}} f(x) \, dx
> = \frac{1}{2\cdot 3^n}\left( f_n(\tfrac{k}{3^n}) + f_n(\tfrac{k-1}{3^n}) \right) + \frac{\alpha}{3^n}\left( f_n(\tfrac{k}{3^n}) - f_n(\tfrac{k-1}{3^n}) \right) $$
>
> where $\alpha = 2\int_{0}^{1} (\psi(3t) - t) \, dt$.

*Remark.* $f$ is a variant of the [*Cantor-Lebesgue function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), with the construction step modified so that the variation diverges fast.

Assuming this theorem, we find that

\begin{align*}
3^n(b_{3^n} - a_{3^n})
&= 3^n \sum_{k=1}^{3^n} \left( f(\tfrac{k}{3^n}) - f(\tfrac{k-1}{3^n}) \right) \int_{\frac{k-1}{3^n}}^{\frac{k}{3^n}} f(x) \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{3^n} \left( f_n(\tfrac{k}{3^n})^2 - f_n(\tfrac{k-1}{3^n})^2 \right) + \alpha \sum_{k=1}^{3^n} \left( f_n(\tfrac{k}{3^n}) - f_n(\tfrac{k-1}{3^n}) \right)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\alpha}{9^n} \sum_{k=1}^{3^n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \psi(3^i \cdot \tfrac{k-1}{3^n} )^2.
\end{align*}

But it is not hard to check that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{3^n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \psi(3^i \cdot \tfrac{k-1}{3^n} )^2
= \left( \psi(0)^2 + \psi(1)^2 + \psi(2)^2 \right)^n. $$

So we have

$$ 3^n(b_{3^n} - a_{3^n})
= \frac{1}{2} + \alpha \left( \frac{\psi(0)^2 + \psi(1)^2 + \psi(2)^2}{9} \right)^n. $$

Finally, we can choose $y_1$ and $y_2$ so that $\frac{\psi(0)^2 + \psi(1)^2 + \psi(2)^2}{9} > 1$ and $\alpha > 0$. Therefore the desired claim $\text{(*)}$ follows. ////

### 2. Proof of Theorem

The following lemma will be useful throughout our proof.

> **Lemma.** For each $m \in \{1, \cdots, 3^n\}$ and $x \in [\frac{m-1}{3^n}, \frac{m}{3^n}]$ we have
>
> \begin{align*}
> f_{n+1}(x)
> &= f_n(\tfrac{m-1}{3^n})
> + \left( f_{n}(\tfrac{m}{3^n}) - f_{n}(\tfrac{m-1}{3^n}) \right) \cdot f_1(3^n x - (m-1)) \\
> &= f_n(x)
> + \left( f_{n}(\tfrac{m}{3^n}) - f_{n}(\tfrac{m-1}{3^n}) \right) \cdot \left( f_1(3^n x - (m-1)) - (3^n x - (m-1)) \right)
> \end{align*}

Indeed, we have

\begin{align*}
f_{n+1}(x) - f_{n+1}(\tfrac{m-1}{3^n})
&= \int_{\frac{m-1}{3^n}}^{x} \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} \psi(3^i t) \, dt \\
&= \left( \prod_{i=1}^{n} \psi \left( 3^i \cdot \tfrac{m-1}{3^n} \right) \right) \cdot \left( \int_{\frac{m-1}{3^n}}^{x} \psi(3^{n+1} t) \, dt \right) \\
&= \left( 3^n \left( f_{n}(\tfrac{m}{3^n}) - f_{n}(\tfrac{m-1}{3^n}) \right) \right) \cdot \left( \frac{f_1(3^n x - (m-1))}{3^n} \right) \\
&= \left( f_{n}(\tfrac{m}{3^n}) - f_{n}(\tfrac{m-1}{3^n}) \right) \cdot f_1(3^n x - (m-1)).
\end{align*}

Plugging $x = \frac{m}{3^n}$ and $f_1(1) = 1$ shows that $f_{n+1}(\tfrac{m}{3^n}) - f_{n+1}(\tfrac{m-1}{3^n}) = f_{n}(\tfrac{m}{3^n}) - f_{n}(\tfrac{m-1}{3^n}) $. From this we easily deduce that $f_{n+1}(\tfrac{m}{3^n}) = f_{n}(\tfrac{m}{3^n})$ and the first half of Lemma follows. Now by using the fact that the graph of $f_n$ is linear on the interval $[\frac{m}{3^n}, \frac{m+1}{3^n}]$, we have

\begin{align*}
f_{n}(x) - f_{n}(\tfrac{m-1}{3^n})
&= \left( f_{n}(\tfrac{m}{3^n}) - f_{n}(\tfrac{m-1}{3^n}) \right) \cdot (3^n x - (m-1))
\end{align*}

and hence the second half of Lemma follows. ////

*Proof of Theorem.* We fist establish the uniform convergence. Let $r = \frac{1}{3}\sup |\psi|$. By our choice of $y_1$ and $y_2$ we know that $r \in [0, 1)$. Also,

$$ \forall m \in \{1,\cdots,3^n\} \ : \quad
\left| f_n(\tfrac{m}{3^n}) - f_n(\tfrac{m-1}{3^n}) \right|
= \frac{1}{3^n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left| \psi(3^i \cdot \tfrac{m}{3^n}) \right|
\leq r^n. $$

Now let $C = \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} |f_1(x) - x|$. Then by Lemma, uniformly in $x \in [0, 1]$ we have

$$ \left| f_{n+1}(x) - f_{n}(x) \right| \leq C r^n. $$

So $(f_n)$ converges uniformly over $[0, 1]$. Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ denote the limiting function. Then $f$ is continuous. Also, by the intermediate step of the proof of Lemma, we know that

\begin{align*}
f_n(\tfrac{k}{3^n})
&= f_{n+1}(\tfrac{k}{3^n})
 = f_{n+1}(\tfrac{3k}{3^{n+1}})
 = f_{n+2}(\tfrac{3k}{3^{n+1}}) \\
&= f_{n+2}(\tfrac{k}{3^n})
 = f_{n+2}(\tfrac{3^2 k}{3^{n+2}})
 = f_{n+3}(\tfrac{3^2 k}{3^{n+2}}) \\
&= f_{n+3}(\tfrac{k}{3^n})
 = \cdots \\
&\quad \vdots
\end{align*}

and hence $f(\tfrac{k}{3^n}) = f_{n}(\tfrac{k}{3^n})$. Now by Lemma again, for $n \geq N$ and $k \in \{1,\cdots,3^N\}$ we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{\frac{k-1}{3^N}}^{\frac{k}{3^N}} f_{n+1}(x) \, dx
&= \int_{\frac{k-1}{3^N}}^{\frac{k}{3^N}} f_{n}(x) \, dx \\
&\hspace{2em} + \sum_{j=3^{n-N}(k-1)}^{3^{n-N}k - 1}
\left( f(\tfrac{j+1}{3^n}) - f(\tfrac{j}{3^n}) \right) \\
&\hspace{8em}\times \int_{\frac{j}{3^n}}^{\frac{j+1}{3^n}} \left( f_1(3^n x - j) - (3^n x - j) \right) dx.
\end{align*}

Using the fact that $\int_{\frac{j}{3^n}}^{\frac{j+1}{3^n}} \left( f_1(3^n x - j) - (3^n x - j) \right) dx = \frac{\alpha}{2 \cdot 3^n}$ and that  we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{\frac{k-1}{3^N}}^{\frac{k}{3^N}} f_{n+1}(x) \, dx
&= \int_{\frac{k-1}{3^N}}^{\frac{k}{3^N}} f_{n}(x) \, dx
 + \sum_{j=3^{n-N}(k-1)}^{3^{n-N}k - 1}
\left( f(\tfrac{j+1}{3^n}) - f(\tfrac{j}{3^n}) \right) \cdot \frac{\alpha}{2\cdot 3^n} \\
&= \int_{\frac{k-1}{3^N}}^{\frac{k}{3^N}} f_{n}(x) \, dx
+ \frac{\alpha}{2\cdot 3^n} \left( f(\tfrac{k}{3^N}) - f(\tfrac{k-1}{3^N}) \right).
\end{align*}

Iterating this relation for $n \geq N$ and using that $f_n \to f$ uniformly and utilizing the equality $f(\tfrac{k}{3^N}) = f_N(\tfrac{k}{3^N})$,

\begin{align*}
\int_{\frac{k-1}{3^N}}^{\frac{k}{3^N}} f(x) \, dx
&= \int_{\frac{k-1}{3^N}}^{\frac{k}{3^N}} f_{N}(x) \, dx
+ \sum_{n\geq N} \frac{\alpha}{2\cdot 3^n} \left( f_N(\tfrac{k}{3^N}) - f_N(\tfrac{k-1}{3^N}) \right) \\
&= \int_{\frac{k-1}{3^N}}^{\frac{k}{3^N}} f_{N}(x) \, dx
+ \frac{\alpha}{3^N} \left( f_N(\tfrac{k}{3^N}) - f_N(\tfrac{k-1}{3^N}) \right).
\end{align*}

Finally, notice that $f_N$ is linear on the interval $[\frac{k-1}{3^N}, \frac{k}{3^N}]$. So the integral is computed as

$$ \int_{\frac{k-1}{3^N}}^{\frac{k}{3^N}} f_{N}(x) \, dx
= \frac{1}{2\cdot 3^N} \left( f_N(\tfrac{k}{3^N}) + f_N(\tfrac{k-1}{3^N}) \right) $$

which proves the desired identity in the theorem. ////

Answer (score 4):

I think this is less easy than it sounds. So far, I only have a solution when $f$ is ${\mathcal C}^2$. The density argument suggested in the comments unfortunately seems to break down along the way (see Martin R's comment below). 
We will show that the limit of $d_n=n(b_n-a_n)$ is $\frac{f(1)^2-f(0)^2}{2}$. With my additional hypothesis on $f$, $|f|+|f''|$ is bounded by some constant $M$ on $[0,1]$. For any subinterval $(a,b) \subseteq [0,1]$, we have 
the following error estimate for the trapezoidal rule (see for example,
[here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/80df/a6fc1262412f3d050e340f06ea7800c5317d.pdf) for a proof)

$$
\Bigg| \int_a^b f(t)dt - (b-a)\bigg(\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}\bigg) \Bigg| \leq \frac{M(b-a)^3}{12} \tag{1}
$$

Using (1) with $a=\frac{k-1}{n}$ and $b=\frac{k}{n}$, we deduce :

$$
\Bigg| \int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}} f(t)dt - \frac{1}{n}\bigg(\frac{f(\frac{k-1}{n})+f(\frac{k}{n})}{2}\bigg) \Bigg| \leq \frac{M}{12n^3} \tag{2}
$$

Multiplying by $f(\frac{k}{n})-f(\frac{k-1}{n})$ :

$$
\Bigg| \bigg(f(\frac{k}{n})-f(\frac{k-1}{n}\bigg)\int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}} f(t)dt - \frac{1}{n}\bigg(\frac{f(\frac{k}{n})^2-f(\frac{k-1}{n})^2}{2}\bigg) \Bigg| \leq 
\frac{M}{12n^3}(|f(\frac{k}{n})|+|f(\frac{k-1}{n})|) \leq
\frac{M^2}{6n^3} \tag{3}
$$

and summing and multiplying by $n$, we deduce

$$
\Big|d_n -\frac{f(1)^2-f(0)^2}{2}\Big| \leq \frac{M^2}{6n^2}
$$

which finishes the proof.

Comment: One point is unclear to me: $f$ can be uniformly approximated by polynomials, and I can see that $|f-p| < \epsilon$ implies $|a_n - a_n'| < C \epsilon$ and  $|b_n - b_n'| < C \epsilon$ where $(a_n') , (b_n')$ are the corresponding sequences for $p$. But I don't yet see why $n(b_n -a_n)$ and $n(b_n' - a_n')$ are arbitrarily close.

Comment: @MartinR I missed that, and now I think this part of the argument is not salvageable. I updated my answer accordingly. Thank you for your helpful comment

Comment: I see what @MartinR says. Still, it is a very nice idea to use the polynomial approximation.

Answer (score 4):

It seems, if I didn't made any mistake, in general $n(b_n-a_n)$ may not converge!  I'll construct an explict counterexample to it. Consider periodic function $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as:

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}0, \{x\} \le \frac{1}{4}\\ 4x - 1, \frac{1}{4} \le \{x\} \le \frac{1}{2}\\ 1, \frac{1}{2} \le \{x\} \le \frac{3}{4}\\ 4 - 4x, \frac{3}{4} \le \{x\} \le 1\end{cases}$$

and put $g_n(x) = g(2^{9n}x)$. We will construct our function $f$ as series $f(x) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty h_ng_n(x)$ with $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty |h_n| < \infty$. We will prove that $2*2^{9n}(b_{2*2^{9n}} - a_{2*2^{9n}})$ is unbounded for suitable choise of $h_n$ thus sequence from the post can not converge. We are interested in the following sum:
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2*2^{9n}} \left(f\left(\frac{k}{2*2^{9n}}\right) - f\left(\frac{k-1}{2*2^{9n}}\right)\right)\int_{\frac{k-1}{2*2^{9n}}}^{\frac{k}{2*2^{9n}}}f(x)dx.
\end{equation}
Since for fixed $n$ everything is absolutely convergent we are basically interested in computing
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2*2^{9n}} \left(g_r\left(\frac{k}{2*2^{9n}}\right) - g_r\left(\frac{k-1}{2*2^{9n}}\right)\right)\int_{\frac{k-1}{2*2^{9n}}}^{\frac{k}{2*2^{9n}}}g_m(x)dx\qquad (1)
\end{equation}
for any $n, r, m > 0$. If $r > n$ then $ \left(g_r\left(\frac{k}{2*2^{9n}}\right) - g_r\left(\frac{k-1}{2*2^{9n}}\right)\right) = 0$ and so we are not interested in this cases. If $r < n$ then $ \left(g_r\left(\frac{k}{2*2^{9n}}\right) - g_r\left(\frac{k-1}{2*2^{9n}}\right)\right)$ has intervals of $k$ on which it is constant(those intervals of the length $2^{-9r}$ up to some factor of $2$ or $4$) and up to constant on them it equals to $0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, \ldots$ Now we have three cases:

1) $m > r$. In this case every copy of $g$ contained in $f_m$ contains in some interval of $k$ and moreover every interval is divided into some number(fixed for fixed $m, r$) of copyes of $g$ so we have sum of the kind $0 + I + 0 - I + ... = 0$ since in every tuple of $4$ intervals we get $0$(from now on lets call those tuples "quads").

2) $m < r$. In this case every quad is contained in some copy of $g$ in $f_m$ and moreover this copy(or, more preciesly, interval, to which it correspondes)  is divided into some number of this quads. Even more since $9$ is a huge number we can say that every quater of copy of $g$ is divided into some number of our quads. On the first and third quaters of $g$ we clearly has zero sum. With some computations one can show that second and fourth quaters also adds up to $0$.

3) $m = r$. In this case we up to some constant interested in $0*\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}}g(x)dx + 1*\int_\frac{1}{4}^\frac{1}{2}g(x)dx + 0*\int_\frac{1}{2}^\frac{3}{4}g(x)dx + (-1)*\int_\frac{3}{4}^1g(x)dx = 0$.

So the remainig case is $r = n$. In this case we would have $ \left(g_r\left(\frac{k}{2*2^{9n}}\right) - g_r\left(\frac{k-1}{2*2^{9n}}\right)\right) = (-1)^{k-1}$. First and second cases could be treated the same as before while in the third case we would have:

$$1*\int_0^\frac{1}{2}g(x)dx + (-1)*\int_\frac{1}{2}^1g(x)dx = \frac{-1}{4}.$$

So (1) is nonzero iff $n = r = m$ and equals to some fixed constant $c < 0$. Thus we have:

$$2*2^{9n}(b_{2*2^{9n}} - a_{2*2^{9n}}) = 2ch_n^2*2^{9n}.$$

Choosing $h_n = 2^{-n}$ we get what we want. Moreover since over some subsequence $h_n$ can decay arbitary slow we can not say anything better than $b_n - a_n \to 0$

In fact, when I was thiking about this problem I treated (1) as some kind of bilinear form on the space of continious functions so I wanted to find sequence of functions $(g_m)$ such that $<g_r, g_m>_n = c\delta_{n, m}\delta_{n, r}$ so I was searching for some kind of continious Rademacher functions.

Comment: It is interesting that we came up with a quite similar idea independently, but of course your construction seems much straightforward than mine. Nice answer :) (+1)

Answer (score 0):

It seems we can compute limit in the case when $f$ is of bounded variation which means that even if counterexample exists it must look very ugly. $f$ is continious so it is uniformly continious so we can assume that  $|\int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}} f(t)dt - \frac{1}{2n}(f(\frac{k}{n}) + f(\frac{k-1}{n}))| < \frac{\epsilon}{n}$ with $\epsilon \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. So we have:

$|n(b_n - a_n) - \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (f(\frac{k}{n}) - f(\frac{k-1}{n}))(f(\frac{k}{n}) + f(\frac{k-1}{n}))|\le \epsilon\sum\limits_{k=1}^n |f(\frac{k}{n}) - f(\frac{k-1}{n})| \le \epsilon Var(f)$

On the other hand $\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (f(\frac{k}{n}) - f(\frac{k-1}{n}))(f(\frac{k}{n}) + f(\frac{k-1}{n})) = \frac{1}{2}(f(1)^2 - f(0)^2)$ so the limit is equal to $\frac{1}{2}(f(1)^2 - f(0)^2)$.